# Why is my graph blank and the numbers incorrect

Tags: python, matplotlib

When you run this, it creates a table from 100 to 200 in steps of 20 and the time taken is calculated. I want a graph that shows the relationship between these two, but when I run it, the graph is blank and the x and y graph numbers are incorrect. (i.e. On the y-axis, I want Speed (100 - 200)

```
import pylab

print "Speed (mph) | Time Taken (s)"
print "==========================="

for i in range(100,201,20):
    Speed = i
    Lowest_Speed = pylab.array( [0.0,100.0,30.0],float)
    Distance_Travelled = pylab.array([20000.0,20000.0,10000.0],float)
    Average_Speed = (Speed + Lowest_Speed)/2.0
    t= Distance_Travelled/Average_Speed
    time_taken=t[0]+t[1]+t[2]


print "%5d"%Speed,"%12.3f"%time_taken

pylab.title  ("Speed vs Time Taken")
pylab.xlabel ("Time Taken (s)")
pylab.ylabel ("Speed (mph)")
pylab.plot ([time_taken] ,[Speed] , 'r-')
pylab.show ()
```

I want 200 going down to 100 in steps of 20, and I want 420 going to 753 (ask shown in calculation). So, a negative correlation

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are only plotting the last values that was assigned to `Speed` and `time_taken` in the loop. Instead, you probably have to add all those values to lists and plot those lists:

```
...
all_speeds = []
all_times = []
for i in range(100, 201, 20):
    ...
    all_speeds.append(Speed)
    all_times.append(time_taken)

...
pylab.plot(all_times, all_speeds, 'r-')
pylab.show()
```

Comment: In addition, the `print "%5d"%Speed,"%12.3f"%time_taken` command should be indented into the loop to print all iterations